# Странное слово или слово-паразит?

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

Я о слове (или это частица?) "мест". В смысле "пока(-)мест". Как это "мест" пишется со словами, уместно ли оно в литературной речи и от чего произошло?

Answer (score 2):

Покамест - то же, что и пока. Но нелитературное, просторечное образование. Из диалектизмов. В некоторых словарях дается с пометой устаревшее, областное (диалектное)